# How to get a mixed SSIS-J2EE system to communicate via messaging?

Tags: ssis, cross-platform, msmq

I'm currently developing an ETL solution which, for various reasons, include **SSIS** components as well as **J2EE** services.

I need the various components to communicate asynchronously via messaging queues. However, the obvious constraint is that SSIS only integrates with MSMQ while it obviously makes sense to use JMS on the Java side.

I have considered the MSMQ/MQSeries Bridge (we use WebsphereMQ internally) but I feel this adds another layer of complexity to the solution.

I now wonder whether there is a simpler solution to achieve cross-platform messaging. The purpose of the messaging approach is really to implement transfer of control between components, rather than pass data. Each component, whether it's a SSIS package or a J2EE service, will read/write from the same underlying database so I wonder if I'm better off just implementing a polling mechanism on either side. Suggestions are welcome.

Christophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your needs you could write your own bridge to move messages between MSMQ and WMQ.  We have done pretty easily using .NET and the IBM XMS libraries.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24011756&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

Comment: hanks, this pointed me to the right direction. In the end, I built a prototype using FUSE media router, which provided a bridge between MSMQ and ActiveMQ, as per the example here: 

http://fusesource.com/wiki/display/ProdInfo/Bridging+MSMQ+with+JMS+using+FUSE-ESB4

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ESB instead of JMS and use the Web Service task in SSIS to connect to and from the ESB via SOAP.

Comment: I've considered that. However, I need 2-way communication. The SOAP facade lets me notify J2EE components from SISS but going back the other way is a different problem. I may consider calling a SSIS package through a WS facade (I've seen examples somewhere), though it doesn't give me what I want

Comment: You may need to use IIS as the web service provider then, but I don't know if that adds too much complexity to your situation.  This article claims that SSIS can be a web service provider without the need for IIS, though: http://whitepapers.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=306563

Comment: Hello John, I see this post is from 2009, I have a similar issue. I have around 20 million which is being delivered through ESB messaging as a continuous feed. How can I use SSIS to get this data filter it and load it in a staging table in SQL server

Answer (score 0):

If all you need in J2EE->SSIS channel is ability to start SSIS package from J2EE, I think the simplest solution is to configure SQL Server Agent Job that runs this package, and then invoke sp_startjob stored proc from Java - should be way easier, and less additional components involved.

I'm not sure what's the best way to call SSIS->J2EE.